# "Have I" or "Had I" as a teasing back question

Tags: past-tense, questions

Let's say we have a statement with questioning and passive-aggressive tone.

> Let's do it this way then, as you've said that this is so convenient!

What would be the correct form to requisition the fact that I have said something, but it was misused or misinterpreted in the sentence above.

1. Have I?
2. Had I?
3. Did I?

I'm interested in correct short form, without second part like (* I said that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Have I" would be correct here. Simple trick - look at it like you're asking the question to which you've received a reply. The reply is:

> as you've said that

which is essentially

> as you have said that

The obvious question to this will be "Have I said that..."

Comment: What to do with statements phrased in the simple past tense, e.g. 'Let's do it this way then, as you said that this is so convenient!' ....?

Comment: Good question @MichaelHarvey have added

Comment: Similarly, you phrase the question in the simple past tense. In the example you've given, it will be "Did I" since the question will be along the lines of "Did I say that this is convenient?" - which is in simple past tense.